# C# / Dapper - passing DataTable as an input parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dapper

In C#, I use Dapper to interact with SQL Server. I call a stored procedure that accepts 2 user-defined tables as parameters.

And I am passing a `DataTable` to my stored procedure. According to this [page](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/364), the syntax to pass a `DataTable` is like this:

```
DataTable value = new DataTable();

DynamicParameters allParameters = new DynamicParameters();
allParameters.Add("name", value, value.AsTableValuedParameter("dbo.udt_MyTable"), ParameterDirection.Input, -1);
```

But I am getting this error:

> Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Dapper.SqlMapper.ICustomQueryParameter' to 'System.Data.DbType?'

What is wrong with my syntax? Is the above functionality not working in Dapper?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
 {
  using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("your_procedure_name"))
    {
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd1.Connection = con1;                                               

    SqlParameter Param = cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_name", dt);
    Param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        con1.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con1.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the posted answer by UsmanMirza will work (this is how I did it before switching to Dapper), the question was asked how to do this using Dapper. In order to do that, instead of putting your parameters inside of the DynamicParameters type variable, just do it "inline (not sure if that's the right word)" and mark the parameter as a table valued parameter there. A good example can be found [here on this dapper samples GitHub page](https://github.dev/yorek/dapper-samples/blob/8b0339e9bd426b5073c6b285a5ef75b0668dbcd2/Dapper.Samples.Advanced/SQLServerFeatures.cs#L50#L72). This is an excerpt:

```
private void ShowTVP(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Testing TVP");
        Console.WriteLine();

        var ut = new DataTable("UserTagsType");
        ut.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(int));
        ut.Columns.Add("Tag", typeof(string));

        ut.Rows.Add(5, "Developer");
        ut.Rows.Add(5, "Data Guy");
        ut.Rows.Add(1, "SysAdmin");

        int affectedRows = conn.Execute(
            "INSERT INTO dbo.[UserTags] SELECT * FROM @ut",
            new
            {
                @ut = ut.AsTableValuedParameter("UserTagsType")
            });    

        Console.WriteLine($"Inserted {affectedRows} values into dbo.[UserTags] via TVP.");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Please add "using" statements, and I will upvote the answer.